# Can I use this charger for my laptop?

Tags: laptop, charger

Information on the Laptop:

- Output +19V 3.42A  65W
- Min Capacity 10.8V  5.0Ah
- Rating +10.8V 5200mAh 56wh
- Model K43E Asus

Information on the Charger:

- Output +19V 4.74A
- Input AC100-240V 50-60Hz 1.5A
- Model: EXA0904YH

As I understood, if the output voltage on the charger matches with the laptop output voltage(in this case both are 19V), it is okay to use it. However, I am not completely sure about this because I do not understand what the Rating part  and what is stated in the minimum capacity mean.

Comment: The "rating" and "min capacity" look like specs of the laptop battery to me. Regarding the charger, I'd also check that the polarity of the plug that goes in the laptop is correct. I don't know if there's variance there but opposite polarity could definitely wreck things up.

Answer (score 2):

Two IC "Integrated Circuit "inside your laptop charging system,
One inside your battery and other one inside your laptop for fully protection. That's to protect the battery from over charging.

If one of them fail the other will protect it.

These days there is third protection inside the batteries: A thermostat sensor.

[image]

If your battery over heated the charger will be disconnect.
all that to protect the battery from over charging or heating.

In your case the voltage is the same but the amps is different, and that's will make your battery over heated.

Keep in mind some laptop vendors build there laptop chargers by measuring the Amps, so they know when the battery is fully charged by knowing the Amps, if you used other charger with different Amps actually your charger will continue charging or discharging before the right values.
and that's will cause a heat, if your battery not contain a temperature sensor or the sensor have fail for some reason that's will cause problems.

[image]

I have a more detailed article about how it works on my blog here  [**here**](http://narzan.weebly.com/my-blog/prevent-mobile-over-charging).

Comment: One plus count more than two minus... SU math :-) Maybe people didn't like self promotion, but in this case IMHO there is nothing bad in your link. BTW don't be cryptic: translate what is IC ;)

Comment: @Hastur Thanks :) for your support. "self promotion" I thought for other thing! ok i will edit it

Comment: I should add that with an amperage bigger than the optimal one, the membrane ([the separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separator_%28electricity%29)) can be subject to a faster deterioration due to mechanical actions and to an increased doping of its polymers (which is made): that's sources of defects. More simply:too much amperage, means bigger/faster flux. On one side less time to charge but on the other it means even push faster(stronger) thought the membrane: you can enlarge the _holes_ that will not stop so efficiently  the particle that want to come back: so it will discharge faster.

Comment: Narzan, I didn't downvote, but I do know something about electronics, and your discussion about the charger amps in your answer and comments is incorrect. The current is determined by the voltage and load. The charger having a higher capacity doesn't "push" more current.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the voltage is the same and the charger has more Amps than laptop can draw. It should work just fine. Just check if the polarity of connectors on the laptop and the charger is the same.